# How did this question get 1500 views in one hour?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I'm not sure I can phrase this other than as "why is my most popular question so popular?" but I am genuinely curious as to how I can get first the Popular Question badge and then, within an hour, the Notable Question badge for my question [LaTeX3 versus pure Lua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45183/latex3-versus-pure-lua).  I remember checking after getting the first one; it had about 1045 views.  Now it has more than 2600 (which is in turn about 50 more than it has a few minutes ago when I got the badge).  Did it get linked somewhere?  Granted that it's a popular question; it's been relatively stable for most of the last week.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least two contributions:

1. [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz) received the [gold Publicist badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/59/publicist?userid=213) ("Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses") as a result of posting it (somewhere).
2. It was also [tweeted to the Stack Exchange Twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/StackTeX/status/171830094120226817).

Comment: Looks like Stefan is the "culprit"; the tweet is a week old.

Answer (score 11):

The question was [posted to Hackernews](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3637023), which can easily drive that kind of traffic if you make it to the frontpage.